# How to write a file a file via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, security, scp

I want to write a file in the Machine B under

> `/home/test` whose permissions are `root:root` and `rwxr-xr-x`.

I have an account on the Machine B, named `testUser`. When logged to the Machine B with this user, I can use `sudo` to write a file under `/home/test`.

However now I want to use `ssh` command on the Machine A to order `testUser@MachineB` to write a file under `/home/test` via `ssh`, but I got the `Permission denied` message when using `scp` to copy a file to `/home/test`. I want to avoid typing password so that these action can be done using a script. Is there any way to solve it?

By the way, I've set ssh-key to login without password authentication.

Is using `setuid` on a executable file on Machine B to write a file under `/home/test` a good way?

Comment: You'll have to delete the file or change its ownership first. Or scp as root - **baaaad idea** ...

Answer (score 1):

You could configure sudo to allow the command `cp foo /home/test/` without a password, and then use this command:

```
ssh testUser@MachineB 'cat > foo && sudo mv foo /home/test/' < my_file
```

Piping data through ssh to a command of your choice on the other end is the general trick here.  You can probably find a dozen other ways to accomplish your goal using variations of this.